# java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.0\..\webapps\ROOT\_cipss\config.ini

Tags: java, apache, jsp, tomcat, servlets

Whenever I type in the hostIP/program name I receive this, but it is suppose to open up a program I am testing out. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
HTTP Status 500 - An exception occurred processing JSP page /index.jsp at line 81


type Exception report

message An exception occurred processing JSP page /index.jsp at line 81

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception
java.io.IOException: An exception occurred processing JSP page /index.jsp at line 81

78:             Timer timer = new Timer();
79:             timer.startTimer();
80: 
81:             DatabaseManager dbFunc = DatabaseManager.getInstance();
82: 
83:             pageContext.setAttribute("dbFunc", dbFunc);
84:         %>


Stacktrace:
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:466)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:396)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:340)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)


root cause
java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.0\..\webapps\ROOT\_cipss\config.ini (The system cannot find the path specified)
    java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
    java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
    java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
    sun.net.www.protocol.file.FileURLConnection.connect(Unknown Source)
    sun.net.www.protocol.file.FileURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
    java.net.URL.openStream(Unknown Source)
    org.ini4j.spi.IniSource.<init>(IniSource.java:55)
    org.ini4j.spi.AbstractParser.newIniSource(AbstractParser.java:68)
    org.ini4j.spi.IniParser.parse(IniParser.java:67)
    org.ini4j.Ini.load(Ini.java:119)
    org.ini4j.Ini.load(Ini.java:114)
    org.ini4j.Ini.load(Ini.java:99)
    org.ini4j.Ini.<init>(Ini.java:69)
    org.kratos.cipss.DatabaseManager.loadConfigFileSettings(DatabaseManager.java:138)
    org.kratos.cipss.DatabaseManager.getInstance(DatabaseManager.java:100)
    org.apache.jsp.index_jsp._jspService(index_jsp.java:215)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:438)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:396)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:340)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)


note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache Tomcat/8.0.30 logs.
```

Apache Tomcat/8.0.30

Answer (score 0):

Your `DatabaseManager` gonna load some config file from this location:

```
C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.0\..\webapps\ROOT\_cipss\config.ini
```

Which apparently does not exist. Add this file!

Comment: I checked and verified that the file is located there and exists and still nothing. I'll check the config file and post more

Comment: Note the two dots in the file path - this looks suspect

Comment: What would I do to fix the ".." error? The file is in the folder and I verified path and file.